Combine 2 lineplots into one with independent y axis
I want to combine two line plots (temp and salinity) into one plot with each side of the y axis for one variable using ggplot2.
Lineplot of salinity and temperature that I want to combine:

This is my code
ggplot(skr_long, aes(x = Dato, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "") +
  scale_x_date(
    breaks = seq(from = min(skr$Dato), to = max(skr$Dato), by = "1 month"),
    labels = scales::date_format("%b %Y")  # Format as month (e.g., Jan 2014)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1) +  # Create separate y-axes for temp and salinity
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "gray", linetype = "longdash"),  # Custom grid lines
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),  # Remove minor grid lines
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),  # Remove x-axis ticks
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),  # Optional: Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
    strip.text = element_text(face = "bold")  # Make facet labels bold
  ) 

How can I do it?

Please read Hadley's comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales
